# Get value of TD with CSS

Tags: html, css

Currently I am getting the `data-name` of the second `<td>` and using CSS to place it inside the second `<td>` and then add a line. Instead, I would like to get the value of what is between the **FIRST** `<td></td>` and place that inside the **SECOND/LAST** `<td></td>` instead of using the `attr(data-name)` is this possible purely with **CSS** and **NO JavaScript/jQuery**?

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/90e6u449/

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td data-name="Some text">Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table tr td:last-child:before {
  content: attr(data-name) ": \A";
  white-space: pre;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: No that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. This is not possible with css.

You cannot get attribute value in other element set in another element.

Comment: Hmm fair enough, any alternatives or suggestions?

Comment: Or may be less or sass would be the option... ( I don't know less or sass)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript or Jquery is the best option.

You cannot make function/action with css.